# Screen rendering but not showing

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm using react-native-navigation v:3.2.0 and react-native v:59.10

(only iOS - android works fine)Only on one push screen rendering but not showing on screen but when trying it on debug mod screen shows.

I'm stuck & don't have any idea what cause this problem?

Anyone can help me or can show way for defining a problem.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What does mean push Screen?

Comment: You mean the Launch screen?

Comment: when i push screen to navigation stack screen render but not show on screen